# Why does jQuery show/hide use display:none instead of visibility:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

`display:none` means that the element isn't rendered as part of the DOM, so it's not loaded until the display property changes to something else.

`visibility:hidden` loads the element, but does not show it.

Why does jQuery use `display:none` for its show/hide functions instead of switching between `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible`?

Comment: @RyanErb did you actually try to read (and understand) the questions or are you just matching keywords?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Because in `display:none`, the element, for all purposes, ceases to exist -- it doesn't occupy any space.
However, in `visibility:hidden`, it's as if you had just added `opacity:0` to the element -- it occupies the same amount of space but just acts invisible.

The jQuery creators probably thought the former would be a better fit for `.hide()`.

Comment: So there should be a way of switching between techniques, because it's sometimes desirable to have the object occupy the required space to perform calculations!

Answer (score 18):

`visibility: hidden` makes an element invisible but does not remove it from the layout of the page. It leaves an empty box where the element was. `display: none` removes it from the layout so it doesn't take up any space on the page, which is usually what people want when they hide something.

Comment: but in some cases visibility is really , usefull .. like you want to keep your layout consistent... and UI doesn't shrink on hide/show

Answer (score 10):

Visibility:hidden makes the element invisible in a way that it still uses space at the page. Display:none makes the element have no space and be completely gone, while it still exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 6):

Visibility just makes the element invisible, but it would still take up space on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`Visibility:hidden` just make the element invisible but it is loaded in DOM so it consumes load time. But `Display:none` does not load the element.