# How do I show divs in an IE print preview page that are programmatically hidden via javascript?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

I have some divs on a page that are hidden via jquery when the page loads up.  Then the user can hide and show them via button clicks.

I have a button that opens up a print preview and media="print" stylesheet that the print preview uses.

I want all the divs to show regardless of whether they are hidden or not when the print preview page is open.  I can't for the life of me figure out how.

I thought I could just have it shown in the print CSS like...

```
.headerContent > * {
    visibility: visible;   
}
```

Where header content is the parent of the hidden divs. This doesn't work though.

jQuery is hiding the divs via .hide() which I believe just flips the visibility property as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery hide() uses `display: none` not `visibility: hidden` . You can read more on why this is so in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160196/why-does-jquery-show-hide-use-displaynone-instead-of-visibilityhidden). To show the divs you can try the following css

```
.headerContent > * { 
 display: block;    
}
```

Or you can use jquery selector and show all divs on print button click with this code

```
$(".headerContent").show();
```