# Using jQuery to select items that have style "visibility:visible" or "visibility:hidden" NOT "display: none"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, visibility

How do you select only visible elements using jQuery?

jQuery selectors :visible and :hidden only respects display:none as *really* hidden? NOT visibility:hidden or visibility:visible.

I understand they are not technically hidden [because they still take their space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160196/why-does-jquery-show-hide-use-displaynone-instead-of-visibilityhidden). I just want to know their state so I can check checkboxes that are visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery :visiblity Selector Test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#VisibleCount").text($("input[type=checkbox]:visible").length); //returns 3. I think it should be 2
        $("#HiddenCount").text($("input[type=checkbox]:hidden").length); //returns 1. I think it should be 2
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #TestArea
    {
        border: solid red 1px;
    }
    #Results
    {
        background-color: Lime;
    }
    .container
    {
        border: solid black 1px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="TestArea">
    <div class="container">
        visibility: hidden;<div style="visibility: hidden;">
            <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        visibility: visible;<div style="visibility: visible;">
            <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        display: none;<div style="display: none;">
            <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        display: inline;<div style="display: inline;">
            <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Results">
    <div>
        Visible Count: <span id="VisibleCount"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Hidden Count: <span id="HiddenCount"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `css` function to get the style of the element, and the `filter` function to select them from a collection of elements:

```
var visible = $('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function() {
   return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
});
```

Comment: +1 for providing a solution (even if you didn't dig up what's happening :)

Comment: Great, thanks guys! I ended up using this with chaining to reduce my result set:

    $("input[type=checkbox]").filter(function() {
    return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
   }).each(function() {
    this.checked = true;
   });

Comment: Also check my answer for more reusability with a custom jquery selector.

Answer (score 11):

From the [jQuery 1.3.2 release notes](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#:visible.2F:hidden_Overhauled) (:visible/:hidden Overhauled):

> - In jQuery 1.3.1 (and older) an    element was visible if its CSS
>     "display" was not "none", its **CSS**
>     **"visibility" was not "hidden", and**
>     its type (if it was an input) was not 
>     "hidden".
> - In jQuery 1.3.2 **an element is visible    if its browser-reported**
>     **offsetWidth    or offsetHeight is**
>     **greater than 0.**
>
> What does this change mean? It means
>   that if your element's CSS display is
>   "none", or any of its parent/ancestor
>   element's display is "none", or if the
>   element's width is 0 and the element's
>   height is 0 then an element will be
>   reported as hidden.

Comment: +1 for digging up what's happening (even if it doesn't provide a solution to the problem).

Answer (score 9):

I've created my own custom selector **:shown** for this. Usage:

```
var visible = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':shown');
```

Or (etc):

```
$("#VisibleCount").text($("input[type=checkbox]:shown").length);
```

Just include this simple code somewhere:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  shown: function (el, index, selector) {
    return $(el).css('visibility') != 'hidden' && $(el).css('display') != 'none' && !$(el).is(':hidden')
  }
});
```