# How to get index of current element taking into account only visible elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to create simple portfolio and show view light box with next before options.

When the user clicked some project I need get the index of the project but taking into account only visible elements.

After click I take

```
$(this).parents("li").filter(":visible").index();
```

But count hidden elements.

How can I get the index only count visible elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar question

[Using jQuery to select items that have style "visibility:visible" or "visibility:hidden" NOT "display: none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279926/using-jquery-to-select-items-that-have-style-visibilityvisible-or-visibility)

```
var projectIndex = $("#grid li").filter(function() {
            return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
        }).index(item) + 1;
```

**item** is variable that hold clicked element.

I hope that be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
  var parents = $(this).closest(".portfolio-items").find("li:visible");
  var parent = $(this).closest("li");
  alert(parents.index(parent));
```

This will returns the index of the passes item based on the set of elements.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k4d6zpay/2/)

Comment: Thanks of the quickly answer. I tested but I get  -1 as result.

Comment: can you add the html as well?

Comment: Check this update https://jsfiddle.net/k4d6zpay/3/ . If you have one element hidden show the index like if element is visible.