# jQuery in JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works except for the jQuery part.
The code makes 6 dots black and stops the interval, but does not fadeIn the div with the id "cs".

What's my mistake?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .dot
    {
        background-color:#666;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        border:1px solid lightgray;
        margin-right:1px;
        float:left;
    }
    body {
            background:url('images/bg.png');
            width:100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        width:1000px;
        position:relative;
    }
    #cs {
        visibility:hidden;
        float: left;
    }
    #loader {
        margin-top:20px;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


(function() {
    var delayInSeconds = 0.5;                           
    var num = 0;
    var changeDot = function() {
        document.getElementById('dot' + num).style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        num++;
        if(num == 6)
        {
            $('#cs').fadeIn('slow');
            window.clearInterval(int);
        }
    };
   var int = window.setInterval(changeDot, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="name">
        <img src="images/as.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
        <div id="dot0" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot1" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot2" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot3" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot4" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot5" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot6" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot7" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot8" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot9" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot10" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot11" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot12" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot13" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot14" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot15" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot16" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot17" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot18" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot19" class="dot"></div>
        <div id="dot20" class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="cs">
        <img src="images/cs.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen any error/exception in your browser console?

Comment: use jQuery instead `document.getElementById('dot' + num).style.backgroundColor`. Also make sure you have element with id `cs` and `dot[1-6]`

Comment: Did using `var int = ` not throw any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `display` instead of `visibility`:

```
#cs {
    display:none;
    float: left;
}
```

Also this may be useful: [Why does jQuery show/hide use display:none instead of visibility:hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160196/why-does-jquery-show-hide-use-displaynone-instead-of-visibilityhidden)